# Setting different Hex-Filenames in MPLAB X for different project configurations

Tags: configuration, makefile, microchip, mplab

I want to set different hex file names for different configurations of a project. In detail I want to have a release configuration where compiler optimization is turned on and a debug configuration where optimization is turned off.

So far I have discovered the possibility to add a second configuration to the project, where I can set a different optimization level. The binary for the other configuration is automatically compiled to another directory but the name of the result hex file stays the same. I tried to change the macro "ImageName" under the "Building" options for the configuration but they are read only and the makefiles containing these macros seem to be automatically regenerated so manual changing is futile.

Is there any way to separate these two builds (one with optimization and one without) by name of the result file? I don't want to release a build without optimization by accident since this is really critical in my current project as I already have experienced.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ***Execute this line after build*** option. It is right above the Macros section (`Right Click` > `Properties` > `Conf:[name]` > `Building`). Commands you type there will be inserted into the auto-generated makefile (*nbproject/Makefile-$CONF.mk*) and executed at the end of the build process.

***Example:***
To copy the output hex file to **"out_dir"** and tag it with the configuration, use this line:

```
${MKDIR} out_dir && ${CP} ${ImagePath} out_dir && ${MV} out_dir/${ImageName} out_dir/${ConfName}_${IMAGE_TYPE}.${OUTPUT_SUFFIX}
```

This line will create "out_dir/", copy the hexfile to the "out_dir" folder and then rename the hexfile to *configuration-name_build-type.hex*.